# Will a thirdparty libary rejected if we go though to Magento technical review of our new plugin?

Tags: magento2, review

we use a library and inserted it in our vendor folder. This library we want to include with our Plugins/Extension’s composer (required: {lib/mylib}). We noticed that the library in vendor folder is using a eval() or a serialize function. Will this library code be rejected if we go though to Magento technical review of our plugin?